# Validating email address in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How exactly do i validate the domain part of an email address? Do i need to first list out the existing domains in my java class or java's `InternetAddress.validate()` will perform it by default? I have used this:

```
public static boolean verifyEmailAddress(String regEmail) {
    boolean result = true;
    try {
        InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(regEmail);
        emailAddr.validate();
    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The request.getParameter has an email address and stored in regEmail..
The problem is even for invalid emails like `san@hhhgggmail.com` its showing valid.. What exactly do i need to do.. Help me out.. And also is this function working fine to those who have used it and tested ?

Comment: Remember to accept helpful answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong perspective. From your application point of view, an email should be considered *valid* (better, useful) if it can receive mail. That's why all those forums keep sending you activation email :) You should send some random string to every new email address and keep it in a *quarantine* state until the user can prove he read the secret.

This is because the domain could exist, or even an MX record for that domain can exist in DNS, but neither of these conditions can guarantee that the address is *valid* - again, when you *validate* something you are really stating that it can be used later in your code for some purpose, and the purpose for an email address is to receive mail

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an automatically way in Java. But I would lookup for a MX record of the domain. If a MX record exists the domain can potentially get mails.

See also [this page](http://www.tomred.net/java-extended-email-validation-using-dns-mx-lookup.html) for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [InetAddres.getByName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) on the domain part?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no exactly effective way to vefy it. all we can do is to vefy the pattern, or more you vefy the mail domain such as hhhgggmail.com. but how could you vefy that "san@hhhgggmail.com do exist" ?

SMTP do has a command 'VEFY' but almost all smtp server doesn't implement this command for security reason.

oh, you want to vefy domain. all smtp server need a mx dns record. you can use dnsjava module to validate it. code as ：

```
public static MXRecord digOptimalMxRecords(String domainName) throws TextParseException {
        List<MXRecord> records = DNSHelper.digMxRecords(domainName);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(records)) {
            Collections.sort(records, new Comparator<MXRecord>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(MXRecord o1, MXRecord o2) {
                    return o2.getPriority() - o1.getPriority();
                }
            });
            return records.get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

public static List<MXRecord> digMxRecords(String domainName) throws TextParseException {
    List<MXRecord> list = new ArrayList<MXRecord>();
    Lookup mxLookupper = new Lookup(domainName, Type.MX);
    mxLookupper.run();
    if (mxLookupper.getResult() == Lookup.SUCCESSFUL) {
        Record[] answers = mxLookupper.getAnswers();
        for (Record record : answers) {
            list.add((MXRecord) record);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: oh, you want to vefy domain. all smtp server need a mx dns record. you can use dnsjava module to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore the variable names as they are unprofessional:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmailValidator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    recursion();

}

static void recursion () {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of typing a correct email address!");
    
    System.out.println();
    
    System.out.println("As the game says, enter a correct email address.");

    System.out.println();

    String snow = scanner.nextLine();

    String[] sssp = snow.split("@");
    
    if (sssp.length != 2) {
        
    System.out.println();
        
    System.out.println("This is not a correct email address."); 
    
    System.out.println();
        
    recursion();
    
    } else {

        String regex = "[^a-z0-9._]";

        String regex1 = "^\\.|\\.$";
        
        String regex2 = "\s";
        
        String regex3 = "^$";
        
        String regex7 = "\\._|_\\.";
        
        String regex39 = "__";
        
        String regex19 = "\\.\\.";
        
        String regex20 = "^_|_$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex1, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
        Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile(regex3, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
        Pattern pattern11 = Pattern.compile(regex7, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
        Pattern pattern12 = Pattern.compile(regex19, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
        Pattern pattern13 = Pattern.compile(regex20, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
        Pattern pattern14 = Pattern.compile(regex39, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sssp[0]);

        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(sssp[0]);
        
        Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(sssp[0]);
        
        Matcher matcher3 = pattern3.matcher(sssp[0]);
        
        Matcher matcher11 = pattern11.matcher(sssp[0]);
        
        Matcher matcher12 = pattern12.matcher(sssp[0]);
        
        Matcher matcher13 = pattern13.matcher(sssp[0]);
        
        Matcher matcher14 = pattern14.matcher(sssp[0]);

        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

        boolean matchFound1 = matcher1.find();
        
        boolean matchFound2 = matcher2.find();
        
        boolean matchFound3 = matcher3.find();
        
        boolean matchFound10 = matcher11.find();
        
        boolean matchFound11 = matcher12.find();
        
        boolean matchFound12 = matcher13.find();
        
        boolean matchFound13 = matcher14.find();
        
        String hello = sssp[1];
        
        String[] whoop = hello.split("\\.", 2);
        
        if (whoop.length != 2) {
            
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("This is not a correct email address."); 

        System.out.println();   
            
        recursion();
        
        } else {
            
            String regex4 = "[^a-z]";
            
            String regex5 = "^$";
            
            String regex6 = "\s";
            
            Pattern pattern4 = Pattern.compile(regex4, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            Pattern pattern5 = Pattern.compile(regex5, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            
            Pattern pattern6 = Pattern.compile(regex6, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            
            Matcher matcher4 = pattern4.matcher(whoop[0]);

            Matcher matcher5 = pattern5.matcher(whoop[0]);
            
            Matcher matcher6 = pattern6.matcher(whoop[0]);
            
            boolean matchFound4 = matcher4.find();

            boolean matchFound5 = matcher5.find();
            
            boolean matchFound6 = matcher6.find();
            
            Pattern pattern7 = Pattern.compile(regex4, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            Pattern pattern8 = Pattern.compile(regex5, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            
            Pattern pattern9 = Pattern.compile(regex6, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            
            Matcher matcher7 = pattern7.matcher(whoop[1]);

            Matcher matcher8 = pattern8.matcher(whoop[1]);
            
            Matcher matcher9 = pattern9.matcher(whoop[1]);
            
            boolean matchFound7 = matcher7.find();

            boolean matchFound8 = matcher8.find();
            
            boolean matchFound9 = matcher9.find();
            
            System.out.println();

            if(matchFound || matchFound1 || matchFound2 || matchFound3 || matchFound4 || matchFound5 || matchFound6 || matchFound7 || matchFound8 || matchFound9 || matchFound10 || matchFound11 || matchFound12 || matchFound13) {

                System.out.println("This is not a correct email address.");

                System.out.println();

                recursion();

            } else {

                System.out.println("This is a correct email address.");

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("Do you still want to play? (say yes to play) ");

                System.out.println();

                Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

                String snow1 = scanner1.nextLine();

                if (snow1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                    System.out.println();

                    recursion();

                } else {

                    System.out.println();  

                    System.out.println("Okay, then.");  
                    
                    scanner.close();
                    
                    scanner1.close();
                    
                }

            }   
            
        }
        
    }

}

}
```